# Google Sheets - Transpose row to new column based on cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I have this very obtuse spreadsheet I've been working

Currently I'm using a Transpose row G:P to a column in my second sheet and I want it so the D25 value will affect the range of the Transpose in D14, and whenever D25 is changed, the transpose will update accordingly!

So instead of editing manually $G326:$P326

If D25= 856

It'll change to: $G856:$P856

Here's an example of what I've been working with:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rSbh5KN1ZHz8fF6edP1TSj3sMyBCwGqB4lv_AJ5wAC8/edit?usp=sharing

From what I've read it should be plausible, but I'm not knowledgable enough to get Query to work despite multiple attempts, so any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=tocol(chooserows('Card List (Automated Skills)'!$G:$P,D25))
```

[image]